# How we can use Intel Movidius Neural Compute Stick for custom model in windows

Tags: machine-learning, intel, movidius

How i can run custom  model using Intel Movidius Neural compute stick in windows.
for example style transfer model,which transfer style from one image to other image,files available for this project is UI(javascript) and python file,How we can run this model using intel stick. please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should take help from below link
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/get-started-with-neural-compute-stick